# Wants to open html file in modal pop up from @Html.ActionLink

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I want to open html file in modal pop up from `@Html.ActionLink`. I have path given in `ExampleUrl`  which I am getting from the database. I have written JQuery to do this but FileName getting undefined. Anyone please guide me.

```
 //My code

 @Html.ActionLink("Example", "#", new { FileName = item.ExampleUrl }, new { @data_toggle = "modal", @data_target = "#myModal" })
```

//JQuery

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
            debugger;
            var dataURL = $(this).attr('data-FileName');
            $('.modal-body').load(dataURL, function () {
                $('#myModal').modal({ show: true });
            });

        });
```

My modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
               ...

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The hyperlink with _either_ open the modal, _or_ navigate to the ExampleURL. If you want to insert the contents of ExampleURL into the modal-body, then one option is to use jQuery's $.load() function. You'd have to handle the "click" event of the hyperlink and run it from there.

Comment: @ADyson, Can you please provide me sample solution so that I can follow that.

Comment: Well Mannan's answer kind of beat me to it to be honest. Your edited code above makes no sense because the modal (as shown) doesn't have a "data-Filename" attribute. Try to follow Mannan's answer more closely and use the "click" event of the button instead.

Comment: @ADyson, can't i use link in spite of button?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean? You don't want a hyperlink because that will cause your page to navigate completely to another URL, instead of loading the modal within the existing page. That's what hyperlinks do. If you want your button to _look like_ a hyperlink, you can use CSS to change its appearance.

Comment: @ADyson, Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: @ADyson, when I debug and  check my 'ExampleUrl' , I am getting the value 'abc.html'. but when i click on button to show the content in modal body, it shows error.

Comment: What error? You mean a 404? Please be specific and accurate with your descriptions. Remember we cannot read your screen, or your mind.

Comment: @ADyson, Yes 404. The same error I pasted below. Please provide me solution for this.

Comment: It just means it couldn't find the file on your server. I can't see your server, so I don't know whether abc.html exists in that location or not. You'll have to check that and make sure you're supplying a valid URL.

Comment: @ADyson, Ok. One more concern about the below code. Why my my control does not execute `$('#myModal').modal({show:true});`. When I check, `data-url`, I am getting  `abc.html`. please help me.

Comment: it doesn't execute it because the "load" call is failing (due to the 404), and that "show" command is located within the callback which runs when the "load" operation _succeeds_. It's done that way so that the modal doesn't try to show before the content is ready, and also what would be the point of loading it if there was no content? Probably worth reading http://api.jquery.com/load/ if you haven't already.

Comment: @ADyson, True. I agree with your point. So basically the problem is with `Url`.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Once you get your URL right it should work nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you are using the @Html.ActionLink to open model popup. it's better to use the normal button and avoid some addition code to call server side method like below.

Trigger the modal with a button

```
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success openBtn" data-url="@item.ExampleUrl">Open Modal</button>
```

Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal with Dynamic Content</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now load the content from an external URL in Bootstrap modal popup.

```
<script>
$('.openBtn').on('click',function(){
    var url = $(this).attr("data-url") //your page url
    $('.modal-body').load(url,function(){
        $('#myModal').modal({show:true});
    });
});
</script>
```

EDIT: If you want to put the files in View folder just place the following code in web.config file that allow you to access the static resources like js and html.

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <add name="JavaScriptHandler" path="*.js" verb="*"
     preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />      
  <add name="HtmlScriptHandler" path="*.html" verb="*"
     preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
  <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
  <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
</handlers>
```

Comment: I am getting error **"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 "**

Comment: @Raj that just means your URL is wrong. 404 means "Not Found"

Comment: @Mannan Bahelim, I am trying the same way you did here but my control does not execute `$('#myModal').modal({show:true});`. When I check, `data-url`, I am getting `abc.html`. please guide me.

Comment: @Raj did you check your url is correct ? and also you didnt put the file in view folder

Comment: You could have a ~/Static folder where you could place your HTML files. And then access it like that: http://example.com/yourapplicationname/static/abcd.html